# Superset: How can I edit value labels in chart legend?

Tags: apache-superset

I have a Superset chart and would like to edit the value labels displayed in chart legend. Can I do this without editing the data? I can edit the axis name via Data / Customize, but there seems to be no option to replace the values.

Comment: You can change the label of each metric/column in "Data" section. It will not edit the actual data in the database.